# Permanently change directory in Mac Terminal? (Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 6)

Tags: python, macos, terminal, directory

I want to permanently change the directory on Terminal for Mac. Every time that I open Terminal, it reverts back to the original directory rather than the directory that I want to use. I know how to use the cd command but would rather not enter it every time. Here's an example of what happens. I try to open my program, but have to change the directory.

```
Last login: Sat Sep 21 18:30:38 on ttys000
chad-welchs-pro:~ welch$ ./pw.py
-bash: ./pw.py: No such file or directory
chad-welchs-pro:~ welch$ cd /Users/welch/MyPythonScripts
chad-welchs-pro:MyPythonScripts welch$
```

Comment: Hey, Andrew, I noticed you edited my post so that the Terminal text looks better. Thank you! How can I do that next time?

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to use the same directory you can edit `bashrc` and add `cd /Users/welch/MyPythonScripts` to the end of the file.
Every new terminal that you open will already be in that directory

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do this? If you ever need to do something else with the Terminal it will be annoying to have it start in this directory. Also, you don't need to type `cd /Users/welch/MyPythonScripts`, you just need to type `cd MyPythonScripts`, so it really shouldn't take that long. If you are sure you want to do this, here you go:

1. Open `~/.bashrc` with any text editor. If it doesn't exist, just create it.
2. Navigate to the end of the file
3. Type `cd ~/MyPythonScripts`
4. Save the file and restart Terminal